# Redux Framework has an embedded demo. Click here to activate the sample config file

Tags: plugins, theme-development, theme-options

I developed the theme. Redux Framework configuration file located in the theme directory.
Himself ReduX Framework I installed from the repository Wordpress using the TGM.
But when I install a theme, then this message appears

> Redux Framework has an embedded demo. Click here to activate the
>   sample config file.

and I need to click on the link for load my options!

How can I make so that my settings are automatically loaded?

functions.php in my theme

```
/**
* Redux
*/
if ( class_exists( 'ReduxFramework' ) ) {
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/options-init.php' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! Helped official support. It was necessary to add the following code.

```
add_action( 'redux/loaded', 'remove_demo' );
/**
 * Removes the demo link and the notice of integrated demo from the redux-framework plugin
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'remove_demo' ) ) {
    function remove_demo() {
        // Used to hide the demo mode link from the plugin page. Only used when Redux is a plugin.
        if ( class_exists( 'ReduxFrameworkPlugin' ) ) {
            remove_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', array(
                ReduxFrameworkPlugin::instance(),
                'plugin_metalinks'
            ), null, 2 );

            // Used to hide the activation notice informing users of the demo panel. Only used when Redux is a plugin.
            remove_action( 'admin_notices', array( ReduxFrameworkPlugin::instance(), 'admin_notices' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to this answer. This won't work if you use TGMPA. But if you want to suppress the this message:

> Redux Framework has an embedded demo. Click here to activate the sample config file.

You can add the following to your **functions.php** file.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'override_redux_message', 30);

function override_redux_message() {
    update_option( 'ReduxFrameworkPlugin_ACTIVATED_NOTICES', []);
}
```

This will prevent the message from showing.
Hope it helps.